# Blur effect on Image View is not working in iOS swift?

Tags: ios, swift

Here is my code:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
     let cell:TableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("TracksCellTracksView") as! TableViewCell

     self.addBlurEffect()

     return cell
 }

 func addBlur effect() {
    let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.ExtraLight)
    let blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
    blurEffectView.frame = albumArt!.bounds
    blurEffectView.autoresizingMask = [.FlexibleWidth, .FlexibleHeight]
    albumArt!.addSubview(blurEffectView)
}
```

This code is not working; Please tell me some alternative way to do it.

For info, I'm using constraints for ImageView.

Comment: where r u adding this code ?

Comment: I wrote a function seperately  let me add entire code

Comment: Do you try to add blur for your every cell?

Comment: Yes Alex p2 I've added but it should come on top right

Comment: what r u trtying to do ?

Comment: does ur cell has imageview ?

Comment: no cells dont contain any image View but My image is updated ther

Comment: my question is, r u trying to apply blur for the whole cell or the imageview in the cell ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to apply the blur effect to the imageview on your table cell, then you need to do this:

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
     let cell:TableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("TracksCellTracksView") as! TableViewCell

     addBlurView(cell.imageView)
     return cell
 }


    func addBlurView(imgView: UIImageView) {
    var blurEffect: UIBlurEffect = UIBlurEffect.effectWithStyle(UIBlurEffectStyleLight)
    self.blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
    self.blurEffectView.frame = imgView.bounds
    self.blurEffectView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight
    imgView.addSubview(blurEffectView)
}
```

You need to pass the reference of the imageview to your blur add method, so that blur gets added to that image view.